# Combining data frames with unequal number of columns

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames, Dat1 and Dat2,

```
Dat1
Col1 Col2 Col3
A1    56   89
```

and

```
Dat2
Col1 Col2 Col4 Col5
A2   49    84   F11
```

Finally I want to have a combined data frame which looks like

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
A1    56   89   NA    NA
A2    49   NA   84    F11
```

Is it possible to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's also `rbind.fill` from `plyr` or `Stack`.

```
library(plyr)

rbind.fill(Dat1, Dat2)

##   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
## 1   A1   56   89   NA <NA>
## 2   A2   49   NA   84  F11

library(Stack)

Stack(Dat1, Dat2)

##   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
## 1   A1   56   89   NA <NA>
## 2   A2   49   NA   84  F11
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to merge with `all=TRUE`:

```
merge(Dat1,Dat2,all=TRUE)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1   A1   56   89   NA <NA>
2   A2   49   NA   84  F11
```

Col5 shows `<NA>` instead of `NA` because it is of mode `factor`

Comment: I would not use merge unless someone wants its inherent matching behavior.